# Access JSON_encode array objects

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem access values from array objects.

From PHP I send my array of objects like this

```
initiate_data(".json_encode($my_array).");
```

From javascript to check the array I have this code

```
function initiate_data(my_array){
window.alert(my_array);}
```

The data I have is

```
{'name':'name1','surname':'surname1','email':'email1'},{'name':'name2','surname':'surname2','email':'email2'},{'name':'name3','surname':'surname3','email':'email3'}
```

I am also able to access the first object

```
window.alert(my_array[0]);
```

The result is

```
{'name':'name1','surname':'surname1','email':'email1'}
```

My problem is that I cannot access name from the object.

I have tried `(my_array[0].name)` and I get undefined

I googled for the solution but I cannot get a solution specific to my problem

when I try to access my_array[0][0] the result {

Thank you for your help thus far

console.log gives me this

```
["{"rec":"1","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"2","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"2","level":"0","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"3","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"1","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"4","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"5","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"3","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"6","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"4","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"7","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"8","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"9","name":"Home","code":"mmenu_home","type":"4","level":"0","default_view":"show_post"}", "{"rec":"10","name":"Opporunities","code":"mmenu_op…":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_opp_tips"}", "{"rec":"11","name":"Careers","code":"mmenu_careers…e":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_careers"}", "{"rec":"12","name":"Tertiary","code":"mmenu_tertia…":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_tertiary"}", "{"rec":"13","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"14","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"2","level":"0","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"15","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"1","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"16","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"17","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"3","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"18","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"4","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"19","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"20","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"21","name":"News","code":"mmenu_news","type":"4","level":"0","default_view":"show_news"}", "{"rec":"22","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"1","level":"0","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"23","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"2","level":"0","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"24","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"1","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"25","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"2","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"26","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"3","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"27","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"4","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"28","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"5","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"29","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"3","level":"6","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"30","name":"Profile","code":"mmenu_profile…e":"4","level":"0","default_view":"show_profile"}", "{"rec":"31","name":"SMS","code":"sms_send_function…"type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"sms_home"}", "{"rec":"32","name":"SMS","code":"sms_send_function…"type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"sms_home"}", "{"rec":"33","name":"SMS","code":"sms_send_function…"type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"sms_home"}", "{"rec":"34","name":"Learners","code":"learners_mme…":"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_learners"}", "{"rec":"35","name":"Learners","code":"learners_mme…":"3","level":"3","default_view":"view_learners"}", "{"rec":"36","name":"Learners","code":"learners_mme…":"3","level":"4","default_view":"view_learners"}", "{"rec":"37","name":"Learners","code":"learners_mme…":"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_learners"}", "{"rec":"38","name":"Learners","code":"learners_mme…":"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_learners"}", "{"rec":"39","name":"Parents","code":"parents_mmenu…e":"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_parents"}", "{"rec":"40","name":"Parents","code":"parents_mmenu…e":"3","level":"3","default_view":"view_parents"}", "{"rec":"41","name":"Parents","code":"parents_mmenu…e":"3","level":"4","default_view":"view_parents"}", "{"rec":"42","name":"Parents","code":"parents_mmenu…e":"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_parents"}", "{"rec":"43","name":"Parents","code":"parents_mmenu…e":"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_parents"}", "{"rec":"44","name":"Staff","code":"staff_function"…:"3","level":"2","default_view":"staff_view_all"}", "{"rec":"45","name":"Staff","code":"staff_function"…:"3","level":"5","default_view":"staff_view_all"}", "{"rec":"46","name":"Staff","code":"staff_function"…:"3","level":"6","default_view":"staff_view_all"}", "{"rec":"47","name":"SGB","code":"sgb_home","type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"sgb_view_all"}", "{"rec":"48","name":"SGB","code":"sgb_home","type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"sgb_view_all"}", "{"rec":"49","name":"SGB","code":"sgb_home","type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"sgb_view_all"}", "{"rec":"50","name":"Photos","code":"photos_mmenu",…vel":"2","default_view":"view_all_websitephotos"}", "{"rec":"51","name":"Photos","code":"photos_mmenu",…vel":"5","default_view":"view_all_websitephotos"}", "{"rec":"52","name":"Photos","code":"photos_mmenu",…vel":"6","default_view":"view_all_websitephotos"}", "{"rec":"53","name":"Departments","code":"mm_depart…3","level":"2","default_view":"view_departments"}", "{"rec":"54","name":"Departments","code":"mm_depart…3","level":"5","default_view":"view_departments"}", "{"rec":"55","name":"Departments","code":"mm_depart…3","level":"6","default_view":"view_departments"}", "{"rec":"56","name":"Academic","code":"mm_academic"…":"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_academic"}", "{"rec":"57","name":"Academic","code":"mm_academic"…":"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_academic"}", "{"rec":"58","name":"Academic","code":"mm_academic"…":"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_academic"}", "{"rec":"59","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"1","level":"0","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"60","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"2","level":"0","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"61","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"1","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"62","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"63","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"3","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"64","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"4","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"65","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"66","name":"Term","code":"mm_term","type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_term"}", "{"rec":"67","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"1","level":"0","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"68","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"2","level":"0","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"69","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"1","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"70","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"71","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"3","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"72","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"4","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"73","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"74","name":"Sports","code":"mm_sports","type":"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_sports"}", "{"rec":"75","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"1","level":"0","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"76","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"2","level":"0","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"77","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"1","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"78","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"2","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"79","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"3","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"80","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"4","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"81","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"5","default_view":"view_belltimes"}", "{"rec":"82","name":"Timetable","code":"mm_timetabl…:"3","level":"6","default_view":"view_belltimes"}"]
```

**Additional Info****

The php class implements JsonSerializable and I have created a array of the object, I hope this will help in clarifying my problem

**Temporary Fix**

Although they might be a better way to do it, this is what I have done to solve the problem

```
var my_obj = JSON.parse(my_array[0]);
```

Now I am able to access name

```
console.log(my_obj.name);
```

Gives me **name1**

Temporary Fix, Until I am able to pass all the array to a variable.

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($my_array)`

Comment: Have you tried `my_array[0]['name']` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried my_array[0]['name'] and still undefined when I try my_array[0][0] I get '{' So I think is a string, How do I change the string to Object

Comment: Is the php present in same javascript page?

Comment: Before you access `my_array[0].name` make `console.log(my_array[0])` and look at this

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `$my_array` contains json strings:

```
$my_array = array(
    '{"name":"name1","surname":"surname1","email":"email1"}',
    '{"name":"name2","surname":"surname2","email":"email2"}',
    '{"name":"name3","surname":"surname3","email":"email3"}'
);
```

If it is the case, you can create javascript array of it by simple implode and add brackets:

```
initiate_data([".implode(',',$my_array)."]);
```

Answer (score 0):

is the json well encoded??
http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
"obj1": {
    "name": "name1",
    "surname": "surname1",
    "email": "email1"
},
"obj3": {
    "name": "name1",
    "surname": "surname1",
    "email": "email1"
},
"obj2": {
    "name": "name1",
    "surname": "surname1",
    "email": "email1"
}
}
```

Comment: Based on your question it is not because it is {},{},{} and not {{},{},{}}

Comment: you should have something like: {
    "obj1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "surname": "surname1",
        "email": "email1"
    },
    "obj3": {
        "name": "name1",
        "surname": "surname1",
        "email": "email1"
    },
    "obj2": {
        "name": "name1",
        "surname": "surname1",
        "email": "email1"
    }
}

Comment: Or better yet: array with objects: `[ { "name": "name1", "surname": "surname1", "email": "email1" }, { "name": "name1", "surname": "surname1", "email": "email1" } ]